# URL rewriting - url doesnt change in browser

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

please help me with the below issue.

I have a tried apache url rewriting.

actual url is http://myserver/firstpage.html

.htaccess content is

RewriteEngin On
RewriteRule ^alpha& firstpage.html

when I enter myserver/alpha it loads myserver/firstpage.html
but the url remains myserver/apha.

Please tell me what to do to enable the auto change(when i search for myserver/alpha it has to load firstpage.html as well as the url should change to http://myserver/firstpage.html)

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r

Answer (score 0):

Try the `[R]` flag

```
RewriteEngin On 
RewriteRule ^alpha& firstpage.html [R]
```

> Use of the [R] flag causes a HTTP redirect to be issued to the
>   browser. If a fully-qualified URL is specified (that is, including
>   http://servername/) then a redirect will be issued to that location.
>   Otherwise, the current protocol, servername, and port number will be
>   used to generate the URL sent with the redirect.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r